# Issues Opening Window WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm using VB.net and WPF 4.

I cannot seem to open a new window in WPF consistantly. It will work one time, and then the next time I execute the same script, it throws the following exception:

> XAMLParseException occured
>   'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '208'.
>   {Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.}

Here is the script:

```
Dim Window As Window = New GAME_WINDOW
Window.Show()
```

Yes, "GAME_WINDOW" is a legitimate WPF window.

Comment: You should add the first eight lines of XAML for GAME_WINDOW to your question; perhaps one of us will know what's going on wrong.

Comment: I will do that still tomorrow...I'd like to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there is something wrong with the XAML associated with GAME_WINDOW. i.e. GAME_WINDOW.xaml on line 4 . Probably your TypeConverter on that line threw an exception.

Comment: Rebuilt the window I was opening, and it worked. Problem seems to come from changing the "Title" property...